# How do I return the search.score in the results of azure cognitive search in c#

Tags: c#, azure

I want to return the score (azure assigns to each result) for each result and display it to the user.
How do I do this?
My application is in C#.

I know that Azure returns "@search.score" with each result, if you look at the json returned by using their web interface.

But I'm using the C# package called Azure.Search.Documents.

See my sample code below.
I have a model class called Hotel, that returns the azure result into it.

Do I just add a property called searchScore and it will get filled?

I have tried many things.

Thanks.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
private static string _searchURL = "searchURL";
private static string _indexName = "indexName";
private static string _queryApiKey = "queryApiKey";
private async Task SearchQuery()
{
        SearchClient searchClientForQueries = new SearchClient(new Uri(_searchURL), _indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(_queryApiKey));

        SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
        {
            IncludeTotalCount = true,
            SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
            QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full
        };

        options.Select.Add("Name");
        options.Select.Add("Address");

        string searchString = "Name:\"The Hotel Name\" AND Address:\"The Address\"";

        SearchResults<Hotel> response = await searchClientForQueries.SearchAsync<Hotel>(searchString, options);
        
        //how do I get the searchScore from the response that azure assigns to each Hotel result?
    }

    public class Hotel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map the search results to your class properties by using their JsonPropertyName.

```
public class Hotel
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("@search.score")]
    public decimal SearchScore {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [@search.score()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchresult-1.score?view=azure-dotnet) retrieves the document's rankings in comparison to other documents which is returned by the query. If your search conditions are met the result is returned using HTTP requests.

```
POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/hotels/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30
{
    "search": "<query string>",
    "scoringStatistics": "global"
}
```

Here is a [sample](https://dibranmulder.github.io/2020/09/22/Improving-your-Azure-Search-performance/) that you can refer to.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Similarity and scoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-similarity-and-scoring#:%7E:text=%20Similarity%20and%20scoring%20in%20Azure%20Cognitive%20Search,by%20defining%20a%20scoring%20profile.%20Scoring...%20More%20)
2. [Search Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents)
3. [How to work with search results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout)

Comment: Thanks for your comment...I have added some of my sample code.  Do you know how I can get the Searchscore into my C# Hotel object?  The Hotel object is the one that recieves each row from Azure.  And I would like to display Azure's searchScore for each Hotel.